# Matlab: Slicing matrix inside a containers.Map always requires intermediate referencing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, dictionary

*Prologue:*

I am in the process of designing/prototyping a piece of code in Matlab.

As at the moment it is not clear to me which matrices should be returned by my functions, I chose, as a general approach, to bind my returned values in `containers.Map` (as I would do e.g. in python).

Hence, the general setting is

```
  function output = myfoo(args)
      output = containers.Map;
      ...some stuff
      output('outname1') = ...
      output('outname2') = ...

  end
```

this approach should have the advantage of allowing me to add more returned data without messing up the other code too much or break backwards compatibility.

---

*Issue:*

How to deal in a elegant way with matrix slicing?

Say that I need to do something like

```
    output('outname1')(2:end) = ...
```

(which gives an error as two indexes are not allowed and a boring workaround like

```
    temp = output('outname1')
    temp(2:end) = ...
    output('outname1') = temp
```

is required).

**Question:**

Is there a proficient way to deal with this, avoiding all this referencing/copying job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it without a temporary variable. The only case in which a double index is valid in Matlab is for a cell array. In that case, you can use
output{...}(...)

However, in any other case, a double index results in an error.